# Need to retrieve data from a CSV file

Tags: excel

Is there any way to retrieve data from a csv file into an excel sheet without opening the csv file? Data on csv file is continuously being written and updated by a program and i want all the data to reflect in Excel sheet. Any help would be appreciated!

Update: I am working on windows PC. Excel sheet and CSV file are in one folder. I also have a program running that is continuously updating the data in CSV file. If i open CSV file directly then program will stop running. I need an alternative solution to read the data from CSV file without opening it.

Comment: To read a file you need to open it... Can you try to clarify what your problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the excel file is living on a windows box or server. There is no real way and which is why many people opt for using databases backends or even just access files that are designed for multi-access purposes.

However, if you just need to read the file; there might be a few tricks using smb to make it so that it is readable while it is still being written to.

Also, if you have the additional db Microsoft SQL (even the light on the pc in question) you might be able to create and ODBC File DSN to that particular file and allow access to it from multiple locations without it locking.

Hope this gets you moving in the right direction. More detail on the access applications and platforms would help. Is this all happening on the same PC, multiple machines. All windows?

Comment: +1 to just dump it into an Access file instead of a csv.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is just updating the values in CSV file, then you can read the data from it.

Reading live data from excel file

Add the header

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

The function will look like this

```
public void readLiveExcel()
{
Workbook xlwkbook;//To keep workbook name
Worksheet xlsheet;//To keep particular excel sheet 
Sheets excelSheets;// to keep all excel sheets
xlwkbook = (Workbook)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.BindToMoniker(sourcefile);
//Get a reference to the Workbook object by using a file moniker.
excelSheets = xlwkbook.Worksheets;
Worksheet xlsheet=null;//To keep particular excel sheet 
Range excelRange = null;
xlsheet = (Worksheet)excelSheets[sheetName];
//sheetName is the name of sheet
xlsheet.Rows.ClearFormats();
excelRange = xlsheet.UsedRange;    
foreach (Range row in excelRange.Rows)
 {
    int rowNumber = row.Row;
    int columnNumber = row.Column;
    if (excelRange.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber] != null)
    {
         string column1= (excelRange.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber] as Range).Value2.ToString();
         string column2= (excelRange.Cells[rowNumber, columnNumber+2] as Range).Value2.ToString();
        //You will get the data here
        //Process the data here
     }
 }
}
```

During running the application, Excel file might open a popup saying this file is already in use, Do you want to re-open it?    Click Yes

Just try this